# How can I show console.log over Aws Cloudwatch + Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a simple form created and that having one function to console.log all the field values. How can I get these logs to appear on AWS Cloudwath ?

My form -

```
<form role="form"  id="form" name="form" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Enter Name</label>
        <input  ng-model="data.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input ng-model="data.age" type="text" maxlength="3" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Enter Age">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input ng-model="data.address" type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter Address">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="reqCalling()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please Help I have no idea what to do